# Как сделать так чтобы объект исчезал при нажатии на любое место кроме него самого

Tags: javascript, css

В общем я сделал такую toggle функцию, где при нажатии на кнопку обект исчезает и появляется, однако мне еще нужно чтобы он исчезал когда нажму на любое место кроме него самого(включая все его child элементы).

```
function displayOnClick(clickingObjId, displayObj) {
    let status = 1;
    document.getElementById(clickingObjId).onclick = function() {
        if(status == 1){
            document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'block';
            status = 0;
        } else if (status == 0){
            document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'none';
            status = 1;
        }

        return status 

    };
    document.onclick = function (e) {
        if (status !== 1 && e.target !== displayObj){ 
            document.getElementById(displayObj).style.display = 'none';
            status = 1;
        }
    }
};
```

Я пытался сделать это раньше через onclick, e.target !== данному обьекту. Но тогда, либо нажимая на элементы внутри самого обекта он все равно закрывался, либо переставала работать кнопка которая должна открывать его, потому что она находиться за перделами элемента который нужно закрыть => срабатывала команда на его закрытие. В общем нужно чтобы были такие условия:

 
1) чтобы функция работала только когда status == 0;

2) чтобы закрывало элемент при нажатии на любое место кроме него самого(включая все child элементы)

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e=>{
div.style.display = 'none';

})

div.addEventListener('click', e=>{
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Div</div>
```

Comment: Хм вроде скопировал все также, только поменял дивы на свой id, однако выдает ошибку(displayObj.addEventListener is not a function)  `document.body.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  displayObj.style.display = 'none';
 });
 displayObj.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 });`

Comment: ***displayObj***  -- это что? class или id?

Comment: displayObj это id

Comment: правь вопрос... добавь что наработал